# NAT Network is merging sessions

Tags: java, session, jsf, spring-security, nat

I'm developing something for a bunch of users, and when I was testing it, NAT users was merging their information as it was only one session.
How can I split it to show the right information to the right user?

I'm using Java, JSF 1.2 and SpringSecurity.

**Update:**

Or at least, how could I develop something and make sure it's splitted, and one user will only access his own information?

Comment: what makes you think it's NAT merging user data? In most cases NAT operates on much more lower network levels.

Comment: it's happening ONLY with NAT users, that's what makes me think that..
i was wondering if it could be some cache from the network servers, any idea of what it could be?

Comment: First thing I'd start with is NAT-testing. If possible with outbound connection enabled, check if one could gain independent access to mailboxes, google, twitter, facebook without merging session data.

If test passed and no paranoid network security settings detected, then more application info will be needed: some simple, narrowed test case like 'user1 fills out simple form and submits, backing bean is processing request, user2 does the same....' Then expected/actual outcome, state saving mechanism (web.xml), session and spring settings, server platform, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be a stupid (sorry) session handling, that matches sessions by IP. All your NAT users have the same external IP, so they are merged. Better use cookies to handle sessions.

As beliarius says, maybe you already use cookies, but if the cookies are created from the IP they are very useless.

If the app you speak about is not browser based, you will have to send a cookie to your clients and have to implement cookie handling for yourself. Or just use one TCP connection per client, and relogin on reconnect.

Comment: One was to test this theory would be to have two browsers with two different logins running on the same computer. Are the sessions merged?

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to answer of @Daniel, I think there is IP address based affinity configured with incorrect values of the subnet masking. If IP adress based affinity is configured then mask should be  255.255.255.255 to uniquely identify connection based on IP. This should be checked in IP virtual servers too.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens when you have a session cookie that is not regenerating properly each time the session starts. Check your session_id in different clients to test this hypothesis.